# Create a keyboard shortcut for a live template in Intellij / PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, rubymine

How can I add keyboard shortcut in keymap for a custom live template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like to assign a shortcut to specific live template? Not currently possible, please follow [IDEA-67811](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67811) for updates